# Ansible and route53 unsupported parameter for module: connection

Tags: dns, ansible, amazon-route53

I'm trying to run an Ansible playbook with Amazon's Route53 service but I get the error in the title.

```
$ ansible-playbook play-dns.yml
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 
GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]
TASK: [configure dns] ********************************************************* 
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: unsupported parameter for module: connection
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
          to retry, use: --limit @/home/myuser/play-dns.retry
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

This is my play:

```
$ cat play-dns.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: configure dns
    route53:
      command: create
      aws_access_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      aws_secret_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      zone: myzone.info
      record: test.myzone.info
      type: A
      ttl: 7200
      value: 1.1.1.1
      wait: yes
      connection: local
```

And this is my Ansible hosts file:

```
$ cat /etc/ansible/hosts|grep localhost
[localhost]
localhost           ansible_connection=local
```

If I remove ansible_connection=local from the hosts file

```
$ cat /etc/ansible/hosts|grep localhost
[localhost]
localhost
```

then I get this error:

```
$ ansible-playbook play-dns.yml
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 
GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [localhost] => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
    while connecting to 127.0.0.1:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
TASK: [configure dns] ********************************************************* 
fatal: [localhost] => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
    while connecting to 127.0.0.1:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
          to retry, use: --limit @/home/myuser/play-dns.retry
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=2    failed=0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is simply indentation. Currently Ansible is parsing your playbook and seeing the connection line as a parameter to the route53 module which is then complaining that `connection` is not a valid parameter for the module.

Instead you simply need to unindent the line to the same level as the hosts so that Ansible parses it as a parameter to the playbook overall rather than the module:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: configure dns
    route53:
      command: create
      aws_access_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      aws_secret_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      zone: myzone.info
      record: test.myzone.info
      type: A
      ttl: 7200
      value: 1.1.1.1
      wait: yes
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I think this was part of the problem. But now it throws this:

https://paste.fedoraproject.org/321871/29683614/

Comment: Sorry, meant it had to be at the playbook level rather than task level. So you need to be 2 levels of indentation up form where you were.

Comment: Thank you! I made it work! :D "wait: yes" is unneeded. It throws an error. Also "connection: local" is redundant. I also had to give route53 permissions to the user I was invoking the API with in Amazon's console.